# Matlab code to Mathematica, Tensor

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, tensors, matlab

I am trying to convert a Matlab code to Mathematica.
I have a tensor, RF (a,b,c,d) which is constructed from Hamiltonian (Hs) and 2x2 identity matrix (DS):

```
RF(a,b,c,d)=Gamma(d,b,a,c)+conj(Gamma(c,a,b,d))-GaP-GaN
```

where a, b , c and d are the different position of Hs.
In Matlab, it is codded as following as:

```
N=2
%-----------------------------------------------------------
Hs=[-0.3165 , 0.08;0.08,-0.1582]
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%--------------Diagonalization of the Hamiltonian---------------
DS=eye(N,N) ;
DSt=DS' ;
[U,E]=eig(Hs) ;
Ut=U' ;
U_1=inv(U);
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------- Tensor1 -------------------------------------
for a=1:N
    for b=1:N
        for c=1:N
            for d=1:N
                 P=0 ;
                    for n=1:N %Run over the sites n       
                      P=P+Ut(a,:)*DS(:,n)*DSt(n,:)*U(:,b)*Ut(c,:)*DS(:,n)*DSt(n,:)*U(:,d) ;
                    end
                    if  d==c
                        Gamma(a,b,c,d)=P*(E(d,d)-E(c,c));
                    else
                        Gamma(a,b,c,d)=P*(E(d,d)-E(c,c));
                    end;
            end
        end
    end
end

%------------------- Tensor2 -------------------------------------
for a=1:N
    for b=1:N
        for c=1:N
            for d=1:N                
               GaP=0 ;
               if b==d          
                   for i=1:N
                       GaP=GaP+Gamma(a,i,i,c) ;
                   end
               end

               GaN=0 ;
               if a==c
                   for i=1:N
                       GaN=GaN+conj(Gamma(b,i,i,d)) ;
                   end
               end
               RF(a,b,c,d)=Gamma(d,b,a,c)+conj(Gamma(c,a,b,d))-GaP-GaN ;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

In Mathematica, I have tried to code this in following way,

1st-- I diagonalize the Hamiltonian and obtained eigen-vectors (U) with corresponding eigen-values in `HLS`.

2nd-- I defined a function `f1[b_, a_]` which is equivalent to `(E(d,d)-E(c,c))` in Matlab.

3rd-- I defined a function `f[a_, b_, c_, d_]` which equivalent to `Gamma(a,b,c,d)` in Matlab.

4rth -- Using `Table` Function,  I evaluated the `f[a_, b_, c_, d_]` over range on `n`. At this point I have the values for Gamma(a,b,c,d).

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n=2;
Hs = {{-0.3165 , 0.08},{0.08,-0.1582}};
{eigsHS, vecsHS} = Eigensystem[Hs];
U = Transpose[vecsHS];
Ut = Transpose[U];
HLS = DiagonalMatrix[eigsHS];
f1[b_, a_] := Indexed[HLS, {b, b}] - Indexed[HLS, {a, a}];
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Sum[Indexed[Ut, {a}].Indexed[DS, {m}]*
     Indexed[DSt, {m}].Indexed[Ut, {b}]*
     Indexed[Ut, {c}].Indexed[DS, {m}]*
     Indexed[DSt, {m}].Indexed[Ut, {d}], {m, n}]*(f1[a, b]);
Gamma(a,b,c,d) = Table[f[a, b, c, d], {a, n}, {b, n}, {c, n}, {d, n}];
```

But, I am unable to translate second part of Matlab code `%-----Tensor2`, to finally arrive at `RF(a,b,c,d)`. So far, I have tried following option, using `If` condition in `Table`, but the output is different.

```
tesnor2 = 
 Table[If[b == d, f[a, b, c, d], Nothing], {a, n}, {b, n}, {c, n}, {d,
    n}]
```

I will be really grateful for any help.

Comment: [`Gamma`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gamma.html) is a built-in function name. There is a convention that built‐in Wolfram Language objects always have names starting with uppercase (capital) letters. To avoid confusion, always choose names for your own variables that start with lowercase letters. In the Wolfram Language, parentheses are reserved specifically for indicating the grouping of terms, so `gamma(a, b, c, d)` is invalid.

Comment: [Getting Used to the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GettingUsedToTheWolframLanguage.html) may be helpful.

Comment: @creidhne thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is a bit closer to what you want to do.

```
RF = Table[
   Plus[
    f[d, b, a, c],
    Conjugate[f[c, a, b, d]],
    If[b == d, -Sum[f[a, i, i, c], {i, 1, n}], 0],
    If[a == c, -Conjugate[Sum[f[b, i, i, d], {i, 1, n}]], 0]
    ]
   , {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}, {c, 1, n}, {d, 1, n}];
```

Note that I use `Plus` instead of `+` only because it is more legible for code that is spread over several lines.

Don't use `Nothing` in this case. Its effect is that every occurence of it will be removed from an embracing list. So the result will be a ragged array, not a tensor.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.